# Shorter function for GetElementById in JS

Tags: javascript

Is there any easier way to access element by it's Id than this long sentence?

```
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML
```

It is very time consuming for me to write this whole sentence each time.
Is there any better way to access an element in JavaScript?

Comment: You are stuck with it. Jquery has an easier way

Comment: take a function for it with a caching for the elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of document.getElementById in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656581/use-of-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript)

Comment: Use a code editor with auto complete, also helps prevent mistakes in your code if typing isn't your thing.

Comment: This is the Javascript for you! This is how it is. You may try other libraries built on top of the JS like jQuery or Lodash or something which might have a method shorter than the one you've mentioned.

Comment: @Sujit - More accurately, this is the DOM for you. `getElementById` isn't JavaScript method.

Comment: The following is not considered best practice, but all `id` attribute values are used to create global variables, so you *could* in theory do: `example.innerHTML`, provided of course that you did not use that variable for other purposes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/5459839) for more details.

Comment: @RitulLakhtariya, The question you mentioned asks something entirely different. I asked if there is a shorter function or something, not why to add a <p>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, yes, but I wouldn't recommend it. Per [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) (and universally supported by browsers), elements in the DOM with `id` attributes show up as global variables with the `id`'s value as their name. So you *could* use

```
example.innerHTML
```

**But**, the global namespace is crowded and there's a lot going on, with lots of potential for conflicts (for instance, `id="name"` doesn't make `name` refer to the element). Instead, give yourself a handy, reusable function:

```
function gid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

It's also probably worth mentioning that relying on `id`s a lot tends to be a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: thats not exactly answer see they wants smaller in size of answer but you gave more long as he want.

Comment: @RitulLakhtariya - `example` and `gid("example")` are both clearly shorter than `document.getElementById("example")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the element by id

eg:

```
$("#example");
```